# Using Python node in LabView returns Error 1667 (No module named 'PySpin')

Tags: python, image-processing, labview

I have a python node trying to run a program that takes images from a camera, saves it to a directory, and displays it on Labview. The code runs perfectly on its own, but the Close Python Session gives an error saying it can't find the module PySpin, and an error 1667.

[image: LabVIEW diagram]

Here is the exact error message

```
Python Node in GrayScale.vi<APPEND>

Module Path: C:\Users\XXL200010\Desktop\Code testing\Camera\Modified-AcquireAndDisplay.py
Function Name: acquire_and_display_images
Python returned the following error: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>
No module named 'PySpin'
<traceback object at 0x000001F3686E45C0>


 Call Stack information:
['Traceback (most recent call last):
', '  File "C:\Users\XXL200010\Desktop\Code testing\Camera\Modified-AcquireAndDisplay.py", line 26, in <module>
    import PySpin
', "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySpin'
"]
```

How do I fix this?

Update: Labview isn't actually seeing any of the imported modules installed, so the problem isn't just with the PySpin module.

Comment: As the error message says, the Python code is trying to use a module called `PySpin` and can't find it. From a quick web search it looks as if that module is [the Python interface for your camera](https://www.flir.com/products/spinnaker-sdk/). Have you installed that software correctly? Can you call Python code successfully from LabVIEW apart from this issue?

Comment: @nekomatic Labview isn't finding any of the modules I installed for this code. ```PySpin``` was just the first one I had imported, so that's why it showed up. I rearranged the order of the imports and it always said the first import wasn't installed. So once it reads the first module, it exits out of the program all together.

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed, or the same version in more than one place? If so, best guess is that the one where you've installed the modules is not the same as the one LabVIEW is using. If you type `echo %path%` at a command prompt and look for the Python directory, is it where you expect and is there more than one?

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when LabVIEW can't find your Python interpreter, which is *usually* the result of Python not being part of your `%PATH%` environment variable in Windows.

There's a fairly detailed explanation of how to do that [here](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/) (you can ignore `Method 1` here, since you already have Python installed), you'll just need to know the path to where Python is installed on your machine!

**Note** - An (maybe?) easier way to get to the Environment Variable editor than the one shown under `Method 2 > Step 1` in that link is:

1. Search for "**env**" in the Windows search bar and hit Enter (the top result should be "Edit the system environment variables")
2. Click on the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom of the System Properties window

Finally, bear in mind that you'll need elevated permissions to edit environment variables!